# How long does it take for a wave pulse on a string to get reflected from rigid boundary?

Tags: waves, reflection, oscillators, string

This question arises from analysis of standing waves.The incident wave has the equation $$y=Asin(kx-\omega t)$$The reflected wave has the equation$$y=Asin(kx+\omega t +\pi)$$When determining the standing wave equation , we add these two , but that should be correct only if ONE wavepulse from left proceeds exactly when ONE wavepulse from right does , simultaneously , It should imply that the incident pulse take one time period $T$ to change its phase by $\pi$, but I am unable to prove it.

[image]

Here is an animation.To express my question better, I have a diagram too.
[image]

In the diagram the $RED$ wave is a case where reflection takes $T$ time to occur so the by the time an incident pulse turns around completely , the source finishes generating an identical and complete pulse simultaneously.

In the $ORANGE$ wave the pulse takes less than the time period $T$ to turn around so the source is unable to generate a complete pulse.This case cannot be handled by adding the equations I wrote formerly (I believe).

So how much time does the pulse take?

Comment: What are you defining to be the "beginning" and "end" of the phase change? When the peak is not at its maximum?

Comment: As seen in the animation-When the pulse ( I mean the whole bump thing and not only the peak) just reaches the boundary, I take this to be the "beginning" of phase change and when the whole bump turns around completely and resembles the original pulse completely ( except the upside-down orientation ) to be the "end" of phase change.

Comment: Shouldn't it be half the time period? It is pretty obvious I guess.

Comment: The $T$ I was referring to is not for one crest and a trough combined , the pulses I am sending along the string are "one bump" each.

Comment: Yeah... so if the wave moves at the same speed with an instantaneous change in direction, then the time you want is just the time it takes for the wave to move "one pulse width", right? i.e. from $y=0$ everywhere to when the pulse "just touches" the wall, which is when it has moved one pulse width.

Comment: In general the incident wave does not have a "period". What is the "period" of something like a Gaussian pulse, $y = Ae^{-b(x-ct)^2}$ for example? It's straightforward to find the shape and the velocity of the reflected pulse, and if you know that, you know everything about what happens.

Comment: @Aaron Stevens , the pulse does not turn around instantaneously , does it ? I just want to know how much time does it take for that turn around after incident pulse just touches the wall.I hope I am not confusing.

Comment: You need to consider that an impulsive force has been applied by the wall

Comment: Obviously , the wall will have to exert an impulsive force , but the impulse does last for a while in the real world , so what is that 'while'

Comment: So you mean to say that , suppose, a person hits a cricket ball with a bat , thereby changing its momentum, you can find the time for which the impulsive force , which has been provided by the bat,  has acted on that ball

Comment: Not me in person but a computer can , for sure.

Comment: @ADITYAPRAKASH The wave has to be traveling to the left or to the right, it can't just sit there. How could it not be an instantaneous change in direction? It is like when you throw a ball up in the air and it changes direction, the direction change is instantaneous. The difference is that with the ball its speed gradually decreases and then increases in magnitude. For your wave it will be traveling at the same speed magnitude the entire time.

Comment: @ADITYAPRAKASH people here are not computers or machines  I guess. So your question does not seem to fit here .

Comment: @Aaron Stevens , how can it be instantaneous,  just look at the animation , the peak of the pulse  does not touch the wall , it just moves downwards after collision , do you really think a physical point can do that in an 'instant' like 'light-speedy' instant ? sorry if I'm a bit disrespectful here.

Comment: @ADITYAPRAKASH I am not saying the entire process is instantaneous. I am saying the *direction change* is instantaneous. Just like when throwing a ball in the air, you can determine the point in time where the velocity is $0$, and hence at that instant the direction changes. The entire process of the ball moving up and down is of course not instantaneous, but the direction change is. The ball doesn't hit the top of its trajectory, levitate for an extended period of time, and then fall down. In your case the instantaneous direction change is at some time $t_0$ when $y(x,t_0)=0$ for all $x$

Comment: @ADITYAPRAKASH do you go to Prerna classes? In which class are you studying dude? I think you live in Jamshedpur.